# django 1.8.6 - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_smtp_ssl'

Tags: python, django, django-email

I am a bit stuck here working through, Django by example.

I keep getting the error that there is no module names 'django_smtp_ssl.

Here are the mail settings from settings.py

```
EMAIL_HOST='smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'xxx@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '********'
EMAIL_PORT=465
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

command I am using in shell is:

```
send_mail('Django Mail', 'This email was sent with Django', ‘123@msn.com', [‘123@msn.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely that you don't have the package installed. Try

```
pip install django-smtp-ssl
```

Comment: That was the ticket! Thanks. Great book but leaves a lot of the details out :)